# Using multiple computers for number crunching

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, c#-4.0, multiprocessing

I'm currently running some computationally intensive simulations, but they are taking a long time to complete. I've already split the workload across all the available physical cores in my processor. What I'm wondering is how to go about splitting the workload further and assigning it to other computers. I'm contemplating buying a couple Xeon servers and using them for the number crunching.

The one big issue I have is that I'm currently running the program within Visual Studio (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F5</kbd>) as there are two methods which I'm constantly making small changes to.

Any suggestions on how/if it's possible to assign the workload to other computers / if it's possible to still run the program with VS or would I need to create an *.exe each time I wanted to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the problem you're solving.

You can use map/reduce and Hadoop if it's easily parallelizable, like SETI@Home.

You can use something like MPI if it's not, like linear algebra.

Comment: I believe its easily parallelizable. The workload can be split into discrete blocks. Someone had suggested WCF but then i believe i still have the issue that i would need to create an *.exe, install it on each server before i could run it. Any changes i needed to make to those 2 methods would necessitate a new *.exe and re-installing them on the servers. (This is assuming i havent missunderstood anything)

Comment: I'd look into Hadoop and HDInsight: http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/hdinsight-writing-hadoop-map

Comment: From what i can see, it stores the data on HD's. Is it possible to load all the data into ram instead in order to avoid excessive I/O

Comment: Hadoop assumes that your problem is so big that you can't fit it into RAM.  You accept I/O because a solution is not possible without it.

Comment: Have you got a minute to talk in a chat room? Like http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the crux of your problem in this statement "The one big issue i have is that im currently running the program within Visual Studio (Ctrl F5) as there are two methods which im constantly making small changes to."?

Is it the "one big issue" because if you distribute then you can't afford modifying the code on all of the nodes when doing the job so you think about something distributing it for you? If this is the case then I assume that you already know how to split the algo or data in a way that nodes can take take of small parts of the job.

If it's the case - sorry if I misunderstood - then externalise the part that you are "constantly making small changes to" into a file or a DataBase encoded in some simple or more elaborate form depending on what you are changing so you don't need to have your nodes change constantly. Deploy the code on all nodes, connect them to the DB or file which contains the varying bit and enjoy your new Ferrari!

Comment: I usually start the simulation. Once finished, which is usually several hrs atm, i modify a couple methods, then re-run it. Or sometimes i realise ive screwed up, stop it, make some quick changes, and then re-run it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [WMI service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394525%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to start your process on the remote computers. You would build your exe to a shared directory that is visible to the remote computer, then use WMI on the remote computer to launch the exe.

There are plenty of examples out there to do this, but to illustrate, a simple method which assumes no authentication complications is to use a .VBS script file:

```
strComputer = "acomputer"
strCommandLine = "calc.exe"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")

intReturnValue = objProcess.Create(strCommandLine, , , intPID)
WScript.Echo "Process ID: " & intPID
```

You can also use [PsExec from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to handle all the details of making this work.

After building the exe in Visual Studio, you could run it on your local machine to ensure it does what you want, then when you are ready to launch it on the remote systems, you can execute a batch script similar to the above VBS to launch the exe on the remote systems.

You will still need to provide some mechanism to divide up the workload so that each client knows what part of the problem it is supposed to work on. You could provide this information in the command line used to start the remote apps, in a config file in the directory with the exe, in a database table, or use a separate command-and-control type server that the clients connect back to (although with that approach you'll soon get to the stage where you would have been better off with learning to use an existing solution rather than rolling your own).

You may also want to include a remote 'kill switch' of some sort. You could use [PsKill from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx), or if you want a more graceful shutdown, something simple like the existence of a particular file in the same directory as the exe can serve as a flag for the remote processes to shut themselves down.

You could also consider adding [CSScript](http://www.csscript.net/) support to the client so that the remote client programs are static and load and compile a CSScript file to do the work. This might be useful if you encounter some kind of difficulty in frequently redeploying and restarting the client programs, or if you need them to all be slightly different (you might write a program to generate separate script files for each client for example).